# Find points on edge of screen with an angle and radius

Tags: c#, math, angle

I have got a square with the bounds of (0,0) to (800,600) In this raster I have to draw a line, given to me are the Angle and Radius of a line, starting from point (0,0).
These bounds are based on a screen with a resolution of 800x600

I know how to calculate the (X,Y) points from this point, 
X = Radius * Cos(Angle) 
Y = Radius * Sin(Angle)

But from this point I don't know how to continue. In the images below I've defined my use cases. (X3,Y3) are the points I know how to calculate as told above. But how do I find (X1, Y1) and (X2, Y2)?

The Angle and Radius can be all kinds of values, see for example the values below. When both X3 and Y3 are a negative value I know the (X1,Y1) and (X2, Y2) will not fall in the raster.

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

[image: Example 3]

I think this isn't to dificult to calculate, but I just don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line from the origin can be expressed by the equation

```
y = mx
```

where the slope m = y3/x3. You will need a line perpendicular to your first line, which means it has a slope of

```
m' = -1/m
```

Therefore it can be expressed by the equation

```
y = m'(x-x3) + y3
```

The point (X1,Y1) will have X1 = 0 and Y1 can be calculated via Y1 = m'x + y3. The point (X2,Y2) will have Y2 = 0 and X2 = (y - Y2)/m' + x3.

Comment: This resolved my problem. I had to add an exception in case the angle was 90 or 0 degrees, but this calculation is what I needed. Thanks